# Can the SQL Server optimizer use indexes to update auto created statistics?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider the scenario where auto created statistics are created on a column to satisfy a query.

Afterwards; a nonclustered index is created on the column, with or without other key columns.

Could the SQL Server optimizer leverage indexes to update these auto created statistics when running `UPDATE STATISTICS` statements?

Is there a difference between (default) sample rates & fullscan statistic updates when adding these indexes?

```
SELECT @@VERSION;

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU12) (KB4464082) - 14.0.3045.24 (X64)   Oct 18 2018 23:11:05   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 3):

---

### TL;DR

Auto created statistics will be improved by an index if you are using fullscan updates & have the column as the first key column in an index.

(Default) sample rate statistic updates will use the clustered index / heap table scan even when a NCI exists with the column as the first key column.

Even when updating the statistic of the NCI.

As such, updating statistics with a sample rate will not be positively impacted by adding an index.

---

**Setup**

Creating a table with a primary key & 10M rows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.testing(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, val nchar(500));

INSERT INTO dbo.testing  WITH(TABLOCK) (val)
SELECT top(10000000) REPLICATE('b',((ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) % 400))
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt3;
```

*A `nchar(500)` value is used to show a clear difference between statistic updates.*

We can create an auto created statistic on the val column with this query:

```
SELECT val
FROM dbo.testing 
where val = 'bla'
order by val;
```

---

**Full scan stat updates**

Updating the statistic with fullscan:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing([_WA_Sys_00000002_4F5F3681]) WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Results in 127 seconds of cpu tme on my machine:

```
CPU time = 127141 ms,  elapsed time = 80147 ms.
```

Now when we look at the query that the stat updates actually runs:

```
SELECT StatMan([SC0]) FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [val] AS [SC0] FROM [dbo].[testing] WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)  ORDER BY [SC0] ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL  OPTION (MAXDOP 2);
```

We can see that it went parallel on the two cores on my machine & did order by the `val` column.

As a side note, there was also a memory grant & tempdb was used to support the ordering, The memory grant was as high as **12484 MB** or ~ **12 GB**

Let's see what happens when we create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_val
on dbo.testing(val);
```

And re-run the stat update:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing([_WA_Sys_00000002_4F5F3681]) WITH FULLSCAN;
```

This results in an execution time of

```
 CPU time = 10578 ms,  elapsed time = 10882 ms.
```

And the memory grant & tempdb usage is gone since it does not have to sort anymore.

The statistic update with fullscan on the auto created stat **is able** to use the index.

This would also work for an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_val_val2
on dbo.testing(val,val2);
```

But not when creating an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_val2_val
on dbo.testing(val2,val);
```

---

**Sample rates**

If we change the update stats to sample 10 percent instead of doing a fullscan:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing([_WA_Sys_00000002_4F5F3681]) WITH SAMPLE 10 PERCENT
```

Without an index this amounts to

```
CPU time = 10500 ms,  elapsed time = 11100 ms.
```

With an index this amounts to

```
CPU time = 10312 ms,  elapsed time = 11038 ms.
```

Auto created statistics with sample rates are **not positively impacted** by indexes on the column where the column is the first key column.
Why this happens is explained further below

---

**Comparison with updating the index' stats**

As expected, updating the statistic on the index takes the same amount of time as the auto created statistics.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing(IX_val) WITH SAMPLE 10 PERCENT

CPU time = 11203 ms,  elapsed time = 11849 ms.

UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing(IX_val) WITH FULLSCAN;

CPU time = 10938 ms,  elapsed time = 11005 ms.
```

---

**Sampled statistic update on an indexed column stat**

The query used when updating statistics with a sample rate of 10 percent is different:

```
SELECT StatMan([SC0], [SC1], [SB0000]) FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [SC0], [SC1], step_direction([SC0]) over (order by NULL) AS [SB0000]  
FROM (SELECT [val] AS [SC0], [ID] AS [SC1] 
FROM [dbo].[testing] TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (9.999986e+000 PERCENT) WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ) 
AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL_HELPER ORDER BY [SC0], [SC1], [SB0000] ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL  OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

`TABLESAMPLE` will give us random pages and it's explanation can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1308/retrieving-random-data-from-sql-server-with-tablesample/).

The statistic orders by `val,id,step_direction([SC0]) over (order by NULL)`

We can trace the query plan of this `StatMan` query with the profiler & the `Showplan XML Statistics Profile` event:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.testing(IX_val) WITH SAMPLE 10 PERCENT
```

The execution plan shows the clustered index being used, instead of the expected nonclustered index:

[image]

I cannot share the query plan with paste the plan unfortunately, it is malformed.

The same is true for heap tables. The usage of the NCI would not make a difference here, the `TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (9.999986e+000 PERCENT)` retrieves 10 percent of the data pages in a random order. This is why the CI was used.